# How to copy a paste a range when one of the addresses is stored in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code

```
Range("A1:LastTableCell").Copy Worksheets("PasteSheet").Range("PasteToHere").Value
```

I get an error when I run this, and I believe it's because I cannout have variables in the range. LastTableCell for example holds the Address $D$5 and PasteToHere for examples holds the Address $C$1. How would I copy the range from A1 to LastTableCell and then paste to the address in PasteToHere?

I'm very new so I'm not really sure if this is possible? I've tried googling it, but I only find stuff about copying regular addresses that are not stored in a variable.

Here's my complete code. I'm having trouble with the part at the bottom where I need to copy and paste my work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyandPaste2()

'Declaring variables
Dim NonemptyRows As Long
Dim CopyLoopInt As Long
NonemptyRows = 1
CopyLoopInt = 1
Dim SelectionLoopInt As Long
SelectionLoopInt = 1
Dim TableRows As Long
TableRows = 0
Dim TableColumns As Long
TableColumns = 0
Dim LastTableCell
Dim PasteToHere

Worksheets("PasteSheet").Activate
'Need to find first blank row here
    Worksheets("PasteSheet").Range("A1").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
        NonemptyRows = NonemptyRows + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

'Need to find row extent of table
Worksheets("TableSheet").Activate
Worksheets("TableSheet").Range("A1").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    TableRows = TableRows + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

'Need to find column extent of table
Worksheets("TableSheet").Activate
Worksheets("TableSheet").Range("A1").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    TableColumns = TableColumns + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop

'Need to find where to paste to
Worksheets("PasteSheet").Activate
Worksheets("PasteSheet").Range("A1").Select
NonemptyRows = NonemptyRows - 1
ActiveCell.Offset(NonemptyRows, 0).Select
PasteToHere = ActiveCell.Address
MsgBox PasteToHere

'Need to find last and rightmost column of table
Worksheets("TableSheet").Activate
Worksheets("TableSheet").Range("A1").Select
TableRows = TableRows - 1
TableColumns = TableColumns - 1
ActiveCell.Offset(TableRows, TableColumns).Select
LastTableCell = ActiveCell.Address

'Now need to copy and paste the table data

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A1:" & LastTableCell).Copy Worksheets(PasteSheet).Range(PasteToHere).Value`

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but I get the same error ("Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Range class failed").

Comment: The destination is a range, not a value.

Comment: "A1:LastTableCell" must be the name of a range. I doubt that it is. Therefore you probably mean something like `Range(Range("A1"),LastTableCell)` if *LastTableCell* is a range or `Range(Range("A1"), Range("LastTableCell"))` if *LastTableCell* is a named range.

Comment: Ashley, perhaps your `LastTableCell` variable is not proper ReferenceStyle format. Or, if your code is in a Module; which means you need to specify the Worksheet with the range, `ws.Range("A1:LastTableCell")`. Let us know... curious...

Comment: show us the code where your variables values are established

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I'll edit the original post with my complete code so I can format it correctly.  @TedD.

Comment: @JVBA It is in a module! I'll try specifying the worksheet, and I'll report back with my findings. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Range("A1:LastTableCell") → Range("A1",LastTableCell)

OR → Range("A1:" & LastTableCell)